# AWS Chalice, can't get image from POST request

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, rest, amazon-sagemaker, chalice

I'm trying to invoke my sagemaker model using aws chalice, a lambda function, and an API Gateaway.

I'm attempting to send the image over `POST` request but I'm having problem receiving it on the lambda function.

My code looks like:

```
from chalice import Chalice
from chalice import BadRequestError
import base64
import os
import boto3
import ast
import json

app = Chalice(app_name='foo')
app.debug = True


@app.route('/', methods=['POST'], content_types=['application/json'])
def index():
    body = ''

    try:
        body = app.current_request.json_body # <- I suspect this is the problem
        return {'response': body}
    except Exception as e:
        return  {'error':  str(e)}
```

It's just returning

`<Response [200]> {'error': 'BadRequestError: Error Parsing JSON'}`

As I mentioned before, my end goal is to receive my image and make a sagemaker request with it. But I just can't seem to read the image.

My python test client looks like this:

```
import base64, requests, json

def test():

    url = 'api_url_from_chalice'
    body = ''

    with open('b1.jpg', 'rb') as image:
        f = image.read()
        body = base64.b64encode(f)

    payload = {'data': body}
    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

    r = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers)
    print(r)
    r = r.json()
    # r = r['response']

    print(r)

test()
```

Please help me, I spent way to much time trying to figure this out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was able to figure it out with the help of an aws engineer (i got lucky I suppose). I'm including the complete lambda function. Nothing changed on the client.

```
from chalice import Chalice
from chalice import BadRequestError
import base64
import os
import boto3
import ast
import json
import sys


from chalice import Chalice
if sys.version_info[0] == 3:
    # Python 3 imports.
    from urllib.parse import urlparse, parse_qs
else:
    # Python 2 imports.
    from urlparse import urlparse, parse_qs

app = Chalice(app_name='app_name')
app.debug = True


@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def index():
    parsed = parse_qs(app.current_request.raw_body.decode())

    body = parsed['data'][0]
    print(type(body))

    try:
        body = base64.b64decode(body)
        body = bytearray(body)
    except e:
        return {'error': str(e)}


    endpoint = "object-detection-endpoint_name"
    runtime = boto3.Session().client(service_name='sagemaker-runtime', region_name='us-east-2')

    response = runtime.invoke_endpoint(EndpointName=endpoint, ContentType='image/jpeg', Body=body)

    print(response)
    results = response['Body'].read().decode("utf-8")
    results = results['predictions']

    results = json.loads(results)
    results = results['predictions']

    return {'result': results}
```

Answer (score 0):

That error message is because you're not sending a JSON body over to your Chalice app.  One way to check this is by using the `.raw_body` property to confirm:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['POST'], content_types=['application/json'])
def index():
    body = ''

    try:
        #body = app.current_request.json_body # <- I suspect this is the problem
        return {'response': app.current_request.raw_body.decode()}
    except Exception as e:
        return  {'error':  str(e)}
```

You'll see that the body is form-encoded and not JSON.

```
$ python client.py
<Response [200]>
{'response': 'data=c2FkZmFzZGZhc2RmYQo%3D'}
```

To fix this, you can use the `json` parameter in the `requests.post()` call:

```
    r = requests.post(url, json=payload, headers=headers)
```

We can then confirm we're getting a JSON body in your chalice app:

```
$ python client.py
<Response [200]>
{'response': '{"data": "c2FkZmFzZGZhc2RmYQo="}'}
```

Comment: you are right, I needed to body = app.current_request.raw_body.decode() but that was only part of the problem turns out. But thanks, really appreciate the help friend.